# Proxy over Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, socks, torcheck, tor-cloud

I'm running TBB on windows 8. I have clicked on onion symbol on top left, clicked on "preference", Ticked "Use custom proxy settings" and put my socks5 client info.

like this:

SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:9956

I see the IP from socks5 client when I checked on browser.

Can anyone tell me if this means I'm running socks5 over Tor network OR since I don't use "the recommended proxy settings", it means I gave up using Tor.

I see 127.0.0.1:9150 when I tick on "use recommended proxy settings".

Port 9150 is listening port, but I do not know what is using port 9150.

I have never seen accurate answer on this question.

I will appreciate if you can explain this further. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys! But I'm not too clear if this means my internet connection is routing like My pc-->tor-->exitnode-->my socks5(port:9956)-->web or not. Is my connection still encrypted by tor?

Answer (score 3):

This option is for setting the proxy port Tor uses. When you start the Tor Browser Bundle an instance of Tor will also be started. This is what you see listening on Port `9150` and where by default the Tor Browser would connect.

What service is running on port `9956`?

If you start another instance of Tor on port `9956`, you really don't need to.

If you have another Proxy that you require to connect to the internet you should set this inside the wizard, either by clicking on `Open Settings` while starting the Tor Browser Bundle or by clicking on the Tor Button (the onion next to your address bar) and, then `Open Network Settings` and select `This computer needs to use a proxy to access the Internet`. From there you can set the proxy. However, do not use this to connect to an instance of Tor.

Comment: "However, do not use this to connect to an instance of Tor." <-- why not? Would it actually hurt, or just create 2 circuits in a row?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1:9150 is the SOCKS5 service that your local Tor client provides.
Your Tor Browser should use it, as per the recommended settings.

Answer (score 0):

`https://check.torproject.org/?lang=en_US` will tell you if your browser is using Tor.